# how to touch files per each counting in loop in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a bash script and I did:

```
 num=`wc -l /tmp/file.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`
 #echo $num 
 #result is for example 29
 for i in {1..$num}
 do
       touch /tmp/pages/$i.txt
 done
```

I want to touch 1.txt till 29.txt (echo $num ==> 29)

the result is wrong...

how can I write a correct loop like what I said...?

thank you in avanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have `seq`, you can try

```
for i in $(seq $num)
```

but instead of

```
num=`wc -l /tmp/file.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`
```

why don't you just

```
num=$(wc -l < /tmp/file.txt)
```

I guess you are not just touching files inside the loop
but just in case that's what you want, you can do it using `awk`

```
awk '{system("touch /tmp/pages/"NR".txt")}' /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to do it entirely in awk. Alternatively in Bourne shell, `nl file.txt | while read n _; do touch "$n".txt; done`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that brace expansion (such as `{1..3,5}` → `1 2 3 5`) is performed *before* parameter expansion (such as `$num` → `29`), so the former can't depend on the latter. In your case, one option is to use an arithmetic (C-style) `for`-loop:

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= num ; ++i )) ; do
    touch /tmp/pages/$i.txt
done
```

(This is most appealing if you're used to languages where this style of `for`-loop is common. If you prefer foreach-loops, then ray's answer, using the external `seq` utility, is probably the way to go.)